# How to add fee_lines using woocommerce rest API v3?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

Can i use "fee_lines" for below 'booking fee' and 'waiter tip' in rest API of woocommerce ?
If yes then send here example please.

I used like below but not working.

```
    "fee_lines": [
    {
      "name": "7.5% Booking Fee",
"tax_status" : 'taxable',
      "tax_class": 0,
      "total_tax": "77.25",
      "total": "77.25",
      "taxes": [],
      "meta_data":  [] 
    },
  {
      "name": "Waiter Tip (5%)",
"tax_status" : 'taxable',
      "tax_class": 0,
      "total_tax": "115.875",
      "total": "115.875",
      "taxes": [],
      "meta_data":  [] 
    }
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Tax class = 0 as an integer looks wrong to me - [the documentation](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#order-properties) says it's a string. What do you get back from the [list all tax classes](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#list-all-tax-classes) endpoint? The example response there has "standard", "reduced-rate" and "zero-rate". You'd hope the API would give you an error if that's the issue though. Any errors in your site's server error log / WordPress debug log / PHP error log if different?

Comment: You would do better asking somewhere WooCommerce-specific though, e,g, start at https://developer.woo.com/

Comment: @Rup right. Tax class having string.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code that working fine.

```
"fee_lines": [
        { 
            "name": "7.5% Booking Fee",
            "tax_status": "taxable",
            "tax_class": "",
            "total": "26.02",
            "total_tax": "26.02",
            "taxes": [],
            "meta_data": []
        },
        { 
            "name": "Waiter Tip (5%)",
            "tax_status": "taxable",
            "tax_class": "",
            "total": "8.00",
            "total_tax": "8.00",
            "taxes": [],
            "meta_data": []
        }
    ]
```